# How to use a javascript filepath in another javascript file in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 javascript files in a Rails application in `/app/vendor/assets/javascripts/` path. Suppose those files are `jsfile-1.js` and `jsfile-2.js`. In `jsfile-2.js` I have following code

```
var myWorker = new Worker("jsfile-1.js");

first.onchange = function() {
  myWorker.postMessage([first.value,second.value]);
  console.log('Message posted to worker');
}
```

I am using both files in my view (`views/name/name.html.erb`). Added these two lines in my `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require jsfile-1
//= require jsfile-2
```

Now when I visit the page http://localhost:3000/name/name (in my case, controller name is the same as the action name) I am getting following error in my Inspect Element Console (in firefox browser):

```
GET http://localhost:3000/name/jsfile-1.js   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 541ms]
NetworkError: Failed to load worker script at "jsfile-1.js"
```

If I write `new Worker("javascripts/jsfile-1.js")` instead of `new Worker("jsfile-1.js")`, presumably I get this error instead:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/name/javascripts/jsfile-1.js   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 541ms]
```

I have tried with many different paths and nothing seem to work. What will be the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

Few thing to remember here...

1. if **you are adding** js files in `application.js`,..you dont need to add them again in view files.
2. if **you are not adding** js files in `application.js`,then you have to add them in `asset.rb` and then require them in your view file wherever you want.

Now..as you have already added files in `application.js`,they all will be available and ready to use.You may verify this by adding an alert in both of you js files,and they both will trigger.

*So irrespective of your controller/action name,they will be loaded.*

[Rails controller specific assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets)....This might be helpful.

Comment: The javascript file themselves are loading just fine, since I am adding them in `application.js`. The problem is occurring because of the `var myWorker = new Worker("jsfile-1.js")` line. Can't seem to figure out what's going on :/